# return a value from ElapsedEventHandler

Tags: c#

How can I return a value from ShowStatus elapsed event? Here is my code. I would like to return result as YES or NO.

Thanks..

```
        Timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
        Timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ShowStatus);
        Timer1.Interval = 30000;
        Timer1.Enabled = true;

   public void ShowStatus(object source, ElapsedEventArgs evt)
    {
        try
        {
            Timer1.Enabled = false;
            string result;

            IPAddress ip = "127.0.0.1";

            result = FindStatus(ip.ToString()) ? YES: NO;
        }
        Timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    public bool FindStatus(string ip)
    {
        Ping p = new Ping();
         ingOptions opts = new PingOptions();
            opts.DontFragment = true; 
            PingReply rc = p.Send(ip, 120, buff, opts);
            if (rc.Status.Equals(IPStatus.Success)) return true;
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: Where do you want to return it **to**?  Do you want to update a UI element with "YES/NO"?

Comment: Yes. I would like to update UI element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to alter ShowStatus' signature since it has to match the `ElapsedEventHandler` delegate.

You'll have to use a member variable to communicate the current state to other methods:

```
private bool statusFound;

protected void ShowStatus(object source, ElapsedEventArgs evt)
{
    // ...
    statusFound = FindStatus(ip.ToString());
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ok.I will use the member variable.